# Javascript is highlighting all my menu items in homepage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using javascript to highlight my menu items, but it is highlighting all my menu items in homepage, rest of the pages works fine.

1. My javascript:

   ```
   $(function () {
       var url = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
       $('[href$="' + url + '"]').parent().addClass("current_page_item");
   });
   ```
2. My main menu:

   ```
   <div id="menu" class="container">
       <ul>
           <li class="current_page_item"><a href="Home.aspx" accesskey="1" title="">Home</a></li>
           <li><a href="Softcare/SoftcareHome.aspx" accesskey="2" title="">Softcare</a></li>
           <li><a href="Softlearn/SoftlearnHome.aspx" accesskey="2" title="">Softlearn</a></li>
           <li><a href="Software/SoftwareHome.aspx" accesskey="2" title="">Software</a></li>
       </ul>
   </div>
   ```
3. My side menu:

   ```
   <div id="sidemenu">
       <div class="section-title">
           <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="submenutitle" runat="server">
           </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
       </div>
       <ul>
           <li><a href="Home.aspx" accesskey="1" title="">Home</a></li>
       </ul>    
   </div>
   ```

Again, only my homepage is experiencing this problem, i am thinking that it is because the parent of homepage is ~/, that is why it is adding current_page_item class to all menu items, including sub menu items. so i think it is my javascript not working properly in my homepage.

PS. I tried to remove parent() from javascript and it didn't help

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a little hack like this :

```
$(function () {
    var url = '/' + window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    $('[href$="' + url + '"]').parent().addClass("current_page_item");
});
```

And make sure all URLs start with **/** :

```
<div id="menu" class="container">
    <ul>
        <li class="current_page_item"><a href="/Home.aspx" accesskey="1" title="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Softcare/SoftcareHome.aspx" accesskey="2" title="">Softcare</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Softlearn/SoftlearnHome.aspx" accesskey="2" title="">Softlearn</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Software/SoftwareHome.aspx" accesskey="2" title="">Software</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried your suggestion but it doesn't highlight anymore, and the current_page_item from my html is there because no matter what submenu item the user chooses, the current page will stay highlighted in main menu, so the user knows where he is.

Comment: try to `console.log(url)` to see what it prints.

Comment: It is printing Home.aspx

Comment: All your other pages end in **xxxHome.aspx**, you will need to rethink your strategy.

Comment: Yea that is my problem, Even though my other pages have different names than my homepage, it still contains xxxHome.aspx which for some reason allowing the system to get the parent of it too. After changing my Home.aspx to Default.aspx, everything works fine, wish it is unique, so Home.aspx is only Home.aspx. Thanks heaps

Answer (score 0):

The selector which you are using is kinda problematic. On home page it is

```
$('[href$=""]')
```

I mean if you open your site without *Home.aspx* at the end. Just the domain name.

which means *get all the elements with href ending to empty string. I guess that this catches every link.

What if you add

```
if(url == "") {
   $("#menu li").removeClass("current_page_item");
}
```

Comment: If you console.log the url on the home page, what is the result?

Comment: It is printing Home.aspx

Comment: Something strange is happening. Here is a jsfiddle which proves that your code works http://jsfiddle.net/uZzZY/ So, you have something else which mess the selections.

Comment: Thanks Krasimir, found out the problem, the system is reading my other page parents too, because they contain xxxHome.aspx too, so after renaming my Home.aspx to Default.aspx, everything works fine now.

Comment: Aha. I'm glad that you find the problem.